# Complex use of function parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

```
function me(a, b) {
    function he(c, d) {
       if(!a[c]) { 
    } 
  }
}
```

Please someone explain `'if(!a[c])'` for me.
why this square bracket is used here in `[c]`, it is not an array obviously.
What does `if(!a[c])` make sense? What would it be if it is not an array?

Comment: why are you sure that a is not an array? Do you have a function signature to indicate this? If not, I am inclined to say that a is an array or an object.

Comment: Do you have any more information? This type of construct is usually how you would create a closure (advanced javascript) but there isn't a return statement anywhere. It would be great to see some more code or the context in which this takes place.

Comment: Arrays are Objects, square bracket notation works for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument `a` is likely an object.  The syntax:

```
if (!a[c])
```

Checks to see if the property in the variable `c` on the `a` object does not have a truthy value.   This could be if it was `null`, `false`, `undefined` or any other falsey value.

---

The bracket notation can be used with property names.  So, if you have an object like this:

```
var x = { name: "John"};
```

Then, you can access that property like in any of these ways:

```
x.name
x["name"];

// Or, if the property name is in a variable
var prop = "name";
x[prop]
```

Your example is using a version of the last of the above three options when the property name is in another Javascript variable.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about that code.

It is saying, in English, *If the property `c` of `a` is falsey, then the condition is `true`*.

In JavaScript, bracket notation can be used to access properties of an object or members of an array.

For example, `someArray[5]` will access the 6th member of the array, while `someObject['someProp']` will access `someProp` of the object `someObject`.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, properties can be accessed dynamically using the square-bracket syntax.

Consider the following:

```
var person = {name:'Sarah'};
console.log(person.name); // logs 'Sarah';
```

Sometimes, you might want to dynamically access properties of an object, using a variable that holds the name of the property you want to access. The above example could also be written like this:

```
var person = {name:'Sarah'};
var prop = 'name';
console.log(person[prop]); // logs 'Sarah';
```